# Add to cart returns undefined on 1st click, returns 1st product on 2nd click Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a simple project where I create a shopping cart through js. The problem i have is that the first time i click a product , "undefined" is returned, The second time I click an item, the return consits the data of the first item clicked.
For Example if i click bacon the first time, I get undefined and then I click Ham I get the data of bacon.

AddToOrder

```
function addToOrder(val) {
    //if order does not exist than create it
    if (typeof (Storage) !== "undefined") {
        if (localStorage.getItem(val) === null) {
            var qty = 1;
            localStorage.setItem(val, qty);
            console.log("New Product");
            getPro(val);
            console.log("Item is " + prod);
            $("#order").append("<tr> <td>" + prod.Name + " </td> <td> &euro; </td > <td><button class='btn btn-success' onClick='addToOrder()'>Remove From Cart</button></td> </tr > ");
        }
        else if (localStorage.getItem(val) !== null) {

            var attempts = parseInt(localStorage.getItem(val));
            localStorage.setItem(val, ++attempts);
            console.log(attempts);
            console.log("Existing Product");
            localStorage.setItem("product", getPro(val));
            console.log(localStorage.getItem("product"));
            // console.log(pro + " " + localStorage.getItem(val));
        }
    }
    //if product already in order add quantity only  and remove stock
    //removeOne(val); //Remove item from order   
}
```

GetProduct

```
function getPro(id) {

    $.getJSON(urlProducts + "/" + id, function (data) {
        prod = JSON.stringify(data);
        console.log(prod);
    });
}
```

Comment: I think your function getPro(val); is an async function. So you got a timing problem. Because you try execute getPro(val) and instantly log the product after. But the $.getJSON call did not return the answer yet. So you need to add a callback or an await statement. Otherwise this will not work.

Comment: The callback Iwrite on the getPro ?

Comment: Yes, or You can e.g. write this line $("#order").append("<tr> <td>" + prod.Name...  inside the $.getJSON call, right after the line console.log(prod); This should help :)